# PHP regex match all except if contains a comma

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I try to get all value matches from a css font file but i need to exclude a comma after a certain string!

My pattern: `/\.(icon-(?:\w+(?:-)?)+):before\s+{\s*content:\s*"(.+)";\s+}/`

This will give me a php array with a list of icons, and what I need to do is to add to :before a comma like :before, so it will escape if it contains a comma after :before.

My code:

```
$css     = file_get_contents( $path );
$pattern = '/\.(' . $class_prefix . '(?:\w+(?:-)?)+):before(?:!,)\s+{\s*content:\s*"(.+)";\s+}/';

preg_match_all( $pattern, $css, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );

$icons = array();

foreach( $matches as $match ){
  $icon       = $class_prefix . ' ' . $match[1];
  $icon_class = $match[1];
  $icon_name  = str_replace( $class_prefix . '-', '', $match[1] );
  $icon_code  = stripslashes( $match[2] );

  $icons[] = $icon_class;
}

return $icons;
```

I'm trying to read data from this file [CSS File](https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.5/dist/css/ionicons.css) and get all .ion- content parameter of icon.

Comment: `:before(?:!,)`? Is that what you're trying to do? Your pattern expects a whitespace after the word `before` though so, it shouldn't match a comma anyway! Please provide some sample inputs and the expected output.

Comment: I'm trying to read a font css file for example ionicons and in the begining of css file they listed all like `.icon-1:before,.icon-2:before,.icon-3:before { and here css for all of them }`, and this causes to return a blank array because this part of css inside `{ }` has no `content: "";` at all, so it skips the code below this and returns nothing, hope you understand me.

Comment: When posting a regex question, you're expected to provide what you've tried already (you did that) and also provide sample input and your expected output (which you haven't done yet). Please do that by [in the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55436626/edit).

Comment: Thank you Ahmed, i've posted my code and a link of what i'm trying to read with my code.

Comment: Ahmed could you help me out with this issue i’m stuck on it!